# Removing a String -Online Shopping cart

Tags: java

I'm not super familiar with stackoverflow so please be kind! The objective of this part of the code is to : 
removeItem() 
- Removes item from cartItems array. Has a string (an item's name) parameter. Does not return anything.
- If item name cannot be found, output this message: Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void removeItem(String itemName){

        if(count!=0)
            count--;
            int index=-1;
            if (cartItems.length!=0) {
                for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    if(cartItems[i].getName().equals(itemName))
                    {
                    index=index-i;
                    break;
                    }
                }}

                if(index==-1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.");
                }


    }
```

But the problem is nothing ever gets removed. the output stays there...

Comment: Of course nothing gets removed. All you're doing is `index = index-i`. How do you expect the thing to be removed?

Comment: My suggestion is use a collection like list or set, and avoid arrays.

Comment: then how should i go about doing it? sorry i am just very confused..avoiding arrays?

Comment: I never learned how to use a collection in class; i don't think I could use that method

Comment: Arrays can't really be modified in place. You're going to want to use a proper Java collection.

Comment: some help to get started would be grateful as i've never used java collection before

Comment: Please use a HashMap and rewrite your whole method.

Comment: i cannot use HashMap! please send an easier way to do...also starting off code would be nice...pseudo code..

Comment: HashMaps exist for exactly such use-cases so please use a HashMap and dont do scary things with arrays which are not ment to be used like that.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Java have a fixed size.
Say your list is ["wheel", "engine", "window"] with size 3.
and you wanted to remove "engine", you would find the index of "engine" (here it is 1)
and then shift everything after engine down one place, giving you: ["wheel", "window", "window"] with size 2

You'd have a variable (size) that keeps track of the size of the list which you would decrement by one when you remove an item. This will allow you to throw an error if someone tries to access an item with an index larger than or equal to the size of the list.

If you wanted to add engine back again, you would simply do list[size] = "engine", and then increment the size variable by 1.
(e.g.: list[size] = "engine"; size ++) list is now ["wheel", "window", "engine"] and size is now 3.

Now say you wanted to add another part to the list. The size is now three, but there is no more space in the array to put a new item.

When someone tries to add an item when the array is full, you would create a new bigger array (usually 1.5 times the size of the original) and then copy all the items from the old array into it, and insert the new item into this array, then replace the old array with this new larger array.

You could spend your time implementing all of this yourself, or you could use the already existing ArrayList class which does exactly what I have described:

```
List<String> carItems = new ArrayList<>();
carItems.add("wheel");
carItems.add("engine");
carItems.add("window");
```

Now when I want to remove engine i can simply do

```
carItems.remove("engine");
```

and boom, its gone.

You also don't need to worry about filling the array, as it will automatically expand as you add new item to it:

```
carItems.add("door");
```

And you can get items using:

```
carItems.get(i);
```

If you have any questions on this feel free to ask.

(Edit)
Just noticed you are storing an array of CarItems, not strings. In which case you could either implement what I stated above with arrays, but instead of storing strings you store CarItems and search for the CarItem with the name of what needs to be deleted, or use a HashMap.

The HashMap is like an ArrayList, except items inside it are addressed by a key rather than an index. You would want something like:

```
Map<String, CarItem> carItems = new HashMap<>();
```

When you add a CarItem, do:

```
carItems.put(carItem.getName(), carItem);
```

And to remove a carItem given its name do:

```
carItem.remove("engine");
```

For example